# iptables - drop packet in FORWARD chain based on string match not working

Tags: iptables

I am trying to forward traffic from one host to another. It's working but I want to  add url whitelist. The following iptables-save rules still block visits like http://host:8383/api/test

What am I missing?

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7:517]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:161]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8383 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:8001
-A POSTROUTING ! -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

-A FORWARD -p tcp  -m string --string "GET /api" --algo bm --icase -j ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP

COMMIT
```

```
sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 49 packets, 2356 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 5 packets, 200 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "GET /api" ALGO name bm TO 65535 ICASE

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 38 packets, 3060 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Here is the `tcpdump` of a simple curl from another host to my lighttpd server: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FCHsg4PmBR/, so no, you can't really "whitelist" it like that. That's not how TCP or HTTP works.

Comment: You might be able to *blacklist* certain `GET` with that kind of approach though.

Comment: setting policy to ACCEPT then blacklist works but that's not what I want. Any other ideas?

Comment: IPTables matches only IP packets. To reach your target, you need TCP level interception. Maybe the easiest one would be to create a transparent HTTP proxy with Squid.

Comment: There seems to have other options. Squid as suggested. I think a forward proxy using nginx might work too. May have problem with https protocol though.

Comment: you having a classical x and y problem, what do you really want to solve?